# What is this hole for in the controller?

Tags: controllers, ps4

So I was changing the trigger springs in my controller this evening and I noticed a small hole in the back of the controller, which I can only assume to be a reset perhaps?

[image: PS4 controller]

What is this hole actually for?

Comment: My first guess would be ventilation, but as I don't own a Ps4 I can't really tell.

Comment: It's a speed hole. It makes the controller go faster.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You're correct, according to [Sony's documentation](https://support.us.playstation.com/articles/en_US/KC_Article/DualShock-4-Troubleshooting/?), it is the reset button.

These are the instructions on how to reset the controller taken from the documentation:

> If your controller won't pair, won't respond, or is displaying a flashing light, please follow the instructions on how to reset the controller:
>
> 1. Turn off the PlayStation 4.
> 2. Locate the small reset button on the back of the DualShock 4 near the L2 shoulder button.
> 3. Use a small, unfolded paper-clip or something similar to push the button (the button is inside a tiny hole). Hold the button down for a couple of seconds and release.
> 4. After resetting the controller, re-pair the controller with the PS4 by connecting the USB cable to the controller and the system, and turn the PS4 on.
> 5. Press the PS button to log in to the PS4
>
> [image]

Comment: Just wondering but shouldn't this question be closed then? Because of the lack of research. Since it's literally in the documentation. The same way people ask stuff on SO that are being closed because it's in the documentation. So lack of research?

Comment: @Loko "Lack of research" isn't a close reason on Stack Overflow (though it is a downvote reason).

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Yet this question has 23 upvotes :P I'd assume the same things apply on Arqade. Especially when it's found in the documentation.

Comment: @Loko There's plenty of good StackOverflow questions that can be answered by the documentation. Usually they are asking about somewhat obscure or infrequently used features (like a reset button on a controller). The downvoted ones are usually really basic questions (like 'how do i push the x button').

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo I agree with you on the StackOverflow argument but this question is pretty basic as well. I think this question has the upvotes because most people dont care to look up the feature itself. Also I've noticed that it's easier to get upvotes on Arqade than on Stackoverflow. e.g: A question with a funny title already gets at least 5 vote ups because of the title. It might not be a bad thing perse but I don't like it. I'm not gonna complain about this on meta or whatever. Just want to let you know what I think,

Comment: Arqade is a premier resource for gaming and related information. There is no reason why we cannot maintain a good base of answers for everything. People's research may well bring them to this question, which has an accurate answer. Bear in mind that not everyone knows what you know.

Comment: @DavidYell I agree with nothing wrong with having a good base of answers though the answer to this question is so easy to find. I literally googled: `what is the small hole in the back of ps4 controller?` just now and I got this: https://support.us.playstation.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5121/~/dualshock-4-troubleshooting **Normally** questions would be closed because of this. It's like asking: "What's the hole next to the ethernet hole in the ps3?(with a picture)" The answer would be: HDMI. With a detailed instruction about HDMI. Which in my opinion is a terrible question and answer.

Comment: @Loko So you're saying you'd rather people found answers elsewhere and not bring any traffic to the site or people into the community? That's fair enough I guess. Time will tell if it gets closed then. I do feel Arqade is way too picky about things like this though, but that's just me :) Plus HDMI is obvious, this is not in my mind, which is why I thought other people might be interested also. 26 upvotes to me says that 26 people also thought so. Probably best open a question on Meta for further discussion :)

Comment: @DavidYell Maybe I kind of commented everything like I hate the whole concept of your idea(s) **but I dont**, I'm just saying compared to other questions on stackexchange which the moderators closed and the way people respond to questions of this kind is way different on those questions. I'm not saying this question is a good question either. Im just shocked at how many upvotes this has. If I had to choose between upvoting this and downvoting this, I'd choose to downvote it.

Comment: It feels like some people get aroused or something by closing or downvoting questions. Why is it so important to you guys to prevent information from being shared here ? Maybe it's not so prevalent on arqade, but some stacks really do have some zealous mods that are like hunting for questions to shut down, interpersonal for example.