# Ps4 controller won't connect again to PS3 with cable or wireless

Tags: ps3, ps4, controllers

My PS4 controllers used to connect to my PS3 normally, however they will no longer connect via cable or wireless. I have tried resetting the controllers, and using different USB cables. I don't know what's happening.
I also don't have PS3 controllers or a keyboard, and the TV controller version to move it won't work. Does anyone know a solution to this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PS4 Controller not connecting to PS4 and won't reset?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/263064/ps4-controller-not-connecting-to-ps4-and-wont-reset)

Answer (score 1):

[image: Have you tried resetting the controller using a safety pin/needle]
Have you tried resetting the controller by inserting a safety pin/needle in the hole shown in the image(it's on the back of the controller) to click a button that is at the bottom of the hole. after resetting try to connect again.
from
https://ccmindtouch.mindtouch.us/Archive/My_System/PS4/Troubleshooting/DualShock_4_Troubleshooting

Answer (score -1):

Next time, please inform us what has changed before it stopped working, or if any major hardware or software updates had occurred.

A PS4 controller can be plugged into a PS3 using a *Male USB A* to *Male Micro USB B*

[image: Cable]

If this doesn't work, your console, controller or cable may be faulty.

Before starting to wirelessly pair, you must ensure your playstation version is above 4.6. You can check this at Settings > System Settings > System Software

1. Navigate to Settings > Accessory settings.
2. Select **Manage Bluetooth Devices**
3. Register new device
4. Start scanning
5. When it is scanning press the **PS Button** and **Share** on the controller at the same time

If this method doesn't work, feel free to respond.