# DualShock 4 controller won't connect to my PS4

Tags: ps4, controllers

I borrowed a DualShock 4 Controller from a mate, but it won't connect to my PS4.

- I have tried physically connecting it to my PS4;
- I've tried pressing the reset button;
- I have tried pressing the 'PS' button on the controller to link it up while in the BlueTooth settings, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Can you give some more information about what you have tried doing to connect the controller? Have you physically connected it to the PS4 with the USB cable? you need to do this the first time you connect a new controller. What do you mean you 'can't press the button', do you mean nothing happens when you press it?

Comment: Yes and yes n othing happens

Comment: Have you tried charging the controller? It would turn on even if not in range of a connected PS4. So either it's broken or it's dead

Comment: @JackKennedy Does [the answer here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/263064/ps4-controller-not-connecting-to-ps4-and-wont-reset?rq=1) help you?