# How do I pair my controller with other PS4 systems?

Tags: technical-issues, controllers

The PS4 controller, I want to connect to my friends PS4, is a CUH-ZCT2U. It doesn’t have a reset button for some reason and I have also tried resetting the PS4 and what not. It just doesn’t connect.

I have tried a USB wire the Bluetooth thing, but none of that works. The PS4 controller flashes but just doesn’t connect.

Comment: I have a Camo and Days of Play DS4 with the same model number, and they have a reset hole where you can insert something like a clip to reset it. Is located on the side of the screw near L2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PS4 Controller not connecting to PS4 and won't reset?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/263064/ps4-controller-not-connecting-to-ps4-and-wont-reset)

Answer (score 1):

I used my PS4 controller with my PS3 and it worked but with the USB. Have you tryed pluging your DS4 before turning the PS4 on? Doing that when it's all on turn on the DS4.

If you want it wireless make sure your DS4 is turned off, use **other DS4** to make the config, go to **settings > devices > bluetooth devices**. Then hold the **ps** button and the **share** button at the same time for **5 sec**. When the controller you want show up at the screen select it with the other contoller then it's done.

Answer (score 0):

Use a USB cord and plug it into the ps4 and the controller. Turn on the controller. Thats all you have to do, it'll automatically connect.

Comment: I’ve tried that already