# Dualshock4 working only on cable

Tags: ps4, controllers

[image]Couldn't find solution to my problem so making a new thread.
My controller can't work unless plugged in ps/pc
It works perfectly fine on cable but as soon as I unplug it it just turns off.
Also can't be turned on/no led light without being plugged.

I tried resetting it
Then check the battery with multimeter- holds normal amount of charge.
No issues with the usb port, no issue with ps button or the conductive mat under all buttons
Tried resetting connections with PS+share
Tried different cables/ports
Tried restarting the ps
There is no obvious sign of damage on the motherboard.
And I have no idea what could be the problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PS4 Controller not connecting to PS4 and won't reset?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/263064/ps4-controller-not-connecting-to-ps4-and-wont-reset)

Comment: The battery is probably dead. Does it work if you plug it into a phone charger maybe (its the same connector.)

Comment: It doesnt show in the controller menu just blank space instead of bars.
But i know for sure it isn't bad I tried with different batteries and again the same show.
the connector to the motherboard is fine as well after that I don't know what/how to check

Comment: So it's not a first party controller? Sony PS4 controllers don't have removable/replaceable batteries.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf The reseller I bought it is reliable. And I have never seen a controller without removable battery