# My PS4 controller broke so I bought a new one and it won't connect no matter what

Tags: technical-issues, ps4, controllers

My controller broke so I bought a new one, but it isn't recognised by the PS4 at all. The PS4 won't turn on when I press the PS button, I pressed share and the PS button - nothing. It starts flashing white. I plugged it in with a usb cable, nothing. Tried a different cable, nothing. Pressed and held the reset button by the L2 trigger, nothing. Switched off the PS4 and I tried a combination of manoeuvres I read online such as unplugging the PS4, then turning on the controller, then the PS4 etc...

I'm worried the issue is that my console is controller-less for a lack of better term. As in, I didn't have a backup spare controller that was connected previously, so when my only one died then there's nothing connected to the PS4 and I can't make a new connection unless one is already established. Could it be? I don't know if that makes sense.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is your new controller an original PS4 one?

Comment: Maybe see https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/263064/163757

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, I managed to resolve the issue - I used a 3rd cable and that worked. I guess the other 2 arent working. If youre having the same issue try yet another cable in case your previous ones dont work. Thank you again