# (New) PS4 slim controller connection troubles

Tags: ps4, controllers

I am new to this forum but I recently just had my 500G Ps4 slim die on me so I ordered a new one. This is where I need help. I just received my pre-owned 500G Ps4 slim that was ordered from GameStop. Super excited to play I unboxed it and set it up. Since it was obviously reset to factory condition I am on this screen where I have to connect my controller with a usb to continue. I tried every usb cable in my home with 4 different PlayStation controllers and nothing worked… I even went and bought a ps4 specific usb cable and still nothing is working. I can put the ps4 into safe mode but other than that I am stuck on this screen. I tried initializing the system and rebuilding the database. Please help.

Comment: Have you seen https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/263064/ps4-controller-not-connecting-to-ps4-and-wont-reset

Comment: I have reset every controller I have tried and I can use any of the controllers when I am in safe mode with the same usb but on the blue screen I cannot.