# PS4 Controller Issue

Tags: ps4, controllers

Whenever I try to turn my PS4 on via remote, the light starts flashing blue for a few seconds and then nothing. When I manually turn the console on, the remotes do the same thing and won’t turn on. The controller and wire both work when the PS4 is in safe mode and I have tried every safe mode option to no avail. I don’t understand how the controller can connect perfectly in safe mode but not when the device is turned on. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm pretty sure we have a duplicate of this question [somewhere](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=ps4+controller+is%3Aquestion).

Comment: Most likely the controller is old, which means so is its battery. Old batteries hold very little charge.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PS4 Controller not connecting to PS4 and won't reset?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/263064/ps4-controller-not-connecting-to-ps4-and-wont-reset)