# PS4 Controller Making False Inputs

Tags: technical-issues, controllers, ps4

I'm not exactly sure how to title this question, but the situation will make sense after this explanation.

I was playing No Man's Sky yesterday, and noticed that randomly the cursor would start to move to the left. The current controller I use is not more than a few months old, so I thought maybe it was the game. I couldn't seem to accurately reproduce it either, so I kept working at it. Finally, I found a way to 100% reproduce the issue each time;

If I move the left stick directly to the right, the stick will leave a ghost input to the left. However, the catch here is, the L2 button will accelerate this issue. Holding down L2 will indeed move the cursor to the left. I tested this in Overwatch as well. As soon as I press the left stick to the right, I hold down L2, and my character moves to the left.

I've never experienced something like this. I've been very gentle with the controller, haven't dropped it or thrown it around or anything. My research on Google only found information on PS3 controllers with unrelated button issues.

*TL;DR - If I press the left stick to the right, release the left stick, then press and hold L2, the controller sends a strong "move left" signal, in addition to any other function assigned to L2.*

I have already ordered a new controller, but I don't think I need to scrap this one entirely. What could I do to try and salvage this controller?

Comment: It could be a hardware failure.

Answer (score 1):

I pulled this from [an old stack question,](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/210281/what-is-this-hole-for-in-the-controller) I would suggest doing a hard reset on the controller. I know the symptoms don't line up exactly but if its a firmware or software issue it should resolve the problem.

> If your controller won't pair, won't respond, or is displaying a flashing light, please follow the instructions on how to reset the controller:
>
> 1. Turn off the PlayStation 4.
> 2. Locate the small reset button on the back of the DualShock 4 near the L2 shoulder button.
> 3. Use a small, unfolded paper-clip or something similar to push the button (the button is inside a tiny hole). Hold the button down for a couple of seconds and release.
> 4. After resetting the controller, re-pair the controller with the PS4 by connecting the USB cable to the controller and the system, and turn the PS4 on.
> 5. Press the PS button to log in to the PS4

If this doesn't work, then you have a hardware issue on your hands and should look into cleaning your controller.

Comment: Which question did you copy this from?  It's important to give attribution.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. Added to answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue that I fixed during the modding of my control, although don't hold me to this. I had to replace a connecting cable between the board on the controller and the touch pad on top (I know it was a bizarre issue) and it solved this, the faulty lead was causing the touch pad to constantly register when other input was pressed. it would make sense in this case as holding L2 speeds up mouse movement when using the touch pad (At least this used to be the case).