# Why won't my ps4 controller connect to my ps4?

Tags: technical-issues, controllers, ps4

I bluetooth paired my ps4 controller to my ps4 just fine. Then i deleted the bluetooth controller account (ps4 controller)off of my ps3. Now no matter what I do my controller won't work for the ps4. I click the home button and it blinks once then turns off. Someone please help me before I loose it.

Answer (score 3):

I think that pushing the reset button on the controller might help you.

From [this answer:](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/210282/143541)

> If your controller won't pair, won't respond, or is displaying a flashing 
>   light, please follow the instructions on how to reset the controller:
>
> 1. Turn off the PlayStation 4.
> 2. Locate the small reset button on the back
>      of the DualShock 4 near the L2 shoulder button.
> 3. Use a small, unfolded
>      paper-clip or something similar to push the button (the button is
>      inside a tiny hole).
> 4. Hold the button down for a couple of seconds and
>      release.
> 5. After resetting the controller, re-pair the controller with
>      the PS4 by connecting the USB cable to the controller and the system,
>      and turn the PS4 on.
> 6. Press the PS button to log in to the PS4
>
> [image: PS4 controller reset button]

Comment: There is a strong possibility that step 5 is the only one needed here.  The easiest way to pair your DS4 with a PS4 is just to connect it with the cable.

Comment: @Gendreavus: I agree. The reset button is only needed when you can't connect via a cable. After pressing the reset, the DS4 will send out a "broadcast" when activated (which inherently means the DS4 isn't paired to anything) which prompts the PS4 to pair with it (the first PS4 to respond to the request, in the rare case where there are multiple). If you have a cable, all that happens automatically and you can guarantee which PS4 you will pair with (in case of multiple).

Answer (score 0):

It is fundamentally important that you press the PS button on the controller in question while the PS4 is powering up, and the blue light is blinking - do not wait until the system prompts you to press the PS button, it's too late.

1. Turn off console.
2. Connect controller with micro-USB cable.
3. Turn on console manually (button on front left of PS4), and when the button lights up blue press the PS button on the controller.

In my recent experience the system took a couple of extra seconds to recognize the controller, but then it worked. I too tried all of the above troubleshooting techniques and none of them worked until I got the all-important timing correct. You'd think Sony would take care to mention this little detail.