# My PS4 controllers disconnect randomly

Tags: technical-issues, ps4, controllers

At any moment, the controller light turns off, and the controller won't connect. My other controller won't connect at that time either. Only way to fix it, is to turn the PS4 off and on again, but just until it happens again. If I am online, for example watching Netflix, the PS4 crashes as well, but only online. If I am watching Netflix, and i see that the controller light shuts off, it takes about 5-10 sec until Netflix crashes too. And if I am playing an offline game, the controller just shuts of and nothing happens to the game. I just can't turn it on to keep playing. 
I have tried reseting both my controllers. 
Please help ❤️

Comment: Does these threads help? https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/263064/ps4-controller-not-connecting-to-ps4-and-wont-reset and https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/292418/why-wont-my-ps4-controller-connect-to-my-ps4

Comment: No. Those are not the same problems. I have also tried all they have done. Not working

Answer (score -2):

Maybe factory reset on your PS4 but before you do that keep in mind that this maybe not work and IF YOU DO that ALL THE DATA WILL DELETED from your PS4. Try to use wired connection or if you using a wire try not using a wire.

Comment: Tried that. Not working :(

Comment: Thats bad... :(